# generate three characters in console delphi

Tags: delphi

Some time ago I had helped make a program that generated three different letters, the problem is that when I use visual form goes well but when I use it in a program console program always generates the 3 letters equal in this case I always returns AAW

Code.

```
program Project1;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

function gen(): string;

var
  aleatorio: Integer;
  iz: Integer;

var
  finalr: string;
begin

  finalr := '';

  finalr := finalr + Chr(ord('A') + Random(26));
  finalr := finalr + Chr(ord('A') + Random(26));
  finalr := finalr + Chr(ord('A') + Random(26));

  Result := finalr;

end;

begin
  try
    Writeln(gen());
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;

end.
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forgetting to call `Randomize`

```
begin
  try
    Randomize;
    Writeln(gen());
    ..
```

Comment: It's important to note where Sertac put the call to `Randomize`. It's used one time before your code executes, not in the function itself. See the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.Randomize) - link is for XE5 docs, but the use of `Randomize` hasn't changed, so the text is still meaningful.

Answer (score 3):

Delphi's random number generator is pseudo-random based on a linear congruential generator. Such generators produce deterministic output. When you start from the same state, or seed, the same series of values will be generated. Unless you supply a seed, a default seed is used. This explains why repeated runs give identical output - the RNG starts with the same seed each time you run.

To deal with this you should give the RNG a different seed for each run. For instance, simply add a call to [Randomize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Randomize) at the start of your program. This will seed the RNG based on the system time. This is not always the best way to seed an RNG, but it may well be sufficient for your needs.

When should you seed your RNG? Usually you seed it once at process start and that's it. You deviate from that policy when you need to reproduce pseudo-random sequences. In other words, there are scenarios when you actually desire the behaviour that you observed. In such scenarios you need to capture the state of the RNG and then every time you need to reproduce a particular sequence, you restore that state.

Comment: It still uses the time to randomize? Wasn't that the cause of the infamous Delphi 4 random number security vulnerability? Delphi 4 was used for a certain online poker game. A group of people were able to check the server's up time, figure out the initial seed, then use that to deduce the hands of the people they were playing against and cheat them out of hundreds of thousands of dollars before the poker site figured out what was going on. I believe Delphi switched to using the Mersenne Twister RNG after that mess.

Comment: @alcalde You cannot blame Borland for that. That's entirely the programmer. Even now it's LCG. Certainly not Mersenne. Clearly documented as not secure in Emba docs.

Comment: It was a poor randomization method; I found the copy of one of the security warnings that went out from gambling software auditors: "The flaw exists in the card shuffling algorithm used to generate each deck.... In the code, a call to randomize() is included to produce a random deck before each deck is generated. The implementation, built with Delphi 4... seeds the random number generator with the number of milliseconds since midnight... That means the output of the random number generator is easily predicted."

Comment: I apparently misremembered that they fixed the quality of the random number generator. :-( Instead of documenting it as not secure, why not replace it with a better randomize function and add a function to seed the randomizer with system noise or the randomize function some CPUs have? I thought that was the standard practice in development languages today. Windows offers a CryptGenRandom function to get crypto-secure random bytes and POSIX has /dev/urandom. There's no reason to need to use the time at all.

Comment: @alcalde Would you trust Emba to implement secure rng? I wouldn't. They are probably right to leave that to third parties.